# How does this While loop end? - Node Code

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, server

**Hello**, I am currently using the website 'Codeschool.com' and I think the instructors code has an infinite loop in their Node/Javascript code, but I'm not certain.

Here is the code:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  request.on('readable', function () {
    var chunk = null;
    while( null !==(chunk = request.read())) {
      response.write(chunk);
    }
  });
  request.on('end', function() {
    response.end();
  });
}).listen(8080)
```

The instructor says that this code is similar to using request.pipe(response);

I understand the concept, but what's throwing me for a loop (no pun intended) is this while loop, how does it ever end?

Comment: When `request.read()` assigns `null` to `chunk`, the condition fails and it stops because it is now `=== null`.

Answer (score 0):

`request.read()` returns a slice of the available data each time it is called, until there is no more data to be returned, in which case it returns `null`.

At that point, `chunk` also equals `null` and since assignments are expressions that return the assigned value, the condition is false and therefor the while loop ends:

`while ( null !== (chunk = null) ) { ... }`